# ¿Preguntas sobre lenguajes de programación pero no preguntas sobre sus teorías?

Tags: discusión

En referencia a esta pregunta de SOes: [expresar nadie en álgebra relacional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5245/expresar-nadie-en-%C3%A1lgebra-relacional?noredirect=1#comment9643_5245) (aunque estoy seguro de que podría encontrar más).

Fue puesto en espera porque "Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación".

Personalmente, yo consideraría que aunque no fue vinculado la pregunta sobre el álgebra relacional con su contrapartida en SQL, sería una falta no incluirla en este sitio. En efecto, este lenguaje, inventado por  Edgar Frank Codd conocido por crear el modelo relacional de bases de datos en 1970, este lenguaje entonces es el base del lenguaje SQL, de los base de datos...

Aunque este lenguaje es menos conocido que el SQL que fundó, sería una vergüenza declararlo como marginados.

No podemos *programar* con álgebra relacional pero no podemos entender como programar sin el.

Por lo momento [hay esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3086/como-expresar-en-%C3%A1lgebra-relacional-los-cuantificadores) y [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3079/como-expresar-en-%C3%A1lgebra-relacional-las-personas-a-las-que-les-gusten-al-menos) sobre nuestro sitio. Pero ademas, hay mas de tres cientos ejemplos sobre el en ingles: [contestado por usuarios reconocidos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978533/how-to-understand-u-r%C3%B7s-the-division-operator-in-relational-algebra)

**Seria una verguenza cerra preguntas sobre temas teoricos, sobre metalenguajes de programacíon y por eso pido su reapertura.**

Comment: Yo fui uno de los que votó por cerrar, en parte quizás por estar con mentalidad del sitio en inglés donde este tipo de preguntas quizás se ajustaría mejor en Programmers que en SO. Teniendo en cuenta que no hay Programmers en español, fue una decisión algo estricta. Votando para reabrir.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Muchas gracias, señor!

Answer (score 4):

Usualmente en el ambiente laboral para el entorno empresarial se acostumbra trabajar más sobre temas prácticos porque son los que te permiten producir código y generar resultados para la empresa. Esto **no le quita valor** a la ciencia detrás de la programación: la teoría, los enunciados, los modelos matemáticos y científicos que respaldan todo lo que apoya a que tengamos a nuestra disposición numerosas tecnologías y herramientas.

Yo creo que este tipo de preguntas son válidas siempre y cuando sean temas asociados al mundo de la computación e informática. Preguntas por temas como teoría de inteligencia artificial, análisis de algoritmos en tiempo asintótico, álgebra relacional, etc, deberían ser aceptadas en esta comunidad, y se podrían crear etiquetas apropiadas para dichos temas.